# Specialization and LSP violation?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, domain-driven-design, liskov-substitution

I have `Document` and `ExternalDocument` classes in my system, where `ExternalDocument` extends `Document`. The main distinction is that `ExternalDocument` holds onto `externalDocumentId` and `externalEventId` data in order to correlate with the external system.

Documents may be overwrote calling `document.overwrite(a, b, c)`. When overwriting external documents I want to track the `externalEventId` that triggered the change and this is where the design falls apart.

According to the LSP I shouldn't strengthen preconditions in `document.overwrite`. I could implement an `document.externalOverwrite` operation and throw an exception when `document.overwrite` is called directly, but that stills violates the LSP.

The language I use doesn't support generics so I can't go for `Document<T>` either where `T` defines the override contract parameter.

I could solve the problem by not inheriting from `Document` at all and use composition instead, but it feels weird given `ExternalDocument` still **is** a `Document` specialization.

Any guidance?

**EDIT:**

Just to give a little more context, local documents can be overwrote by a local/user process. External documents are a reflection of documents existing in an external system. I want to communicate the fact that we do not have authority over external documents. The state of those documents is updated in response to remote system events and I want to be able to correlate every state change with a corresponding `externalEventId`.

Note that some local document operations remain valid on the external ones though, like assigning the document, etc. I'm also trying to keep the business logic within the model as much as possible to avoid an anemic domain model.

After thinking a little more about it I think I may have conflated both "overwrite" operations as one although overwriting a local document & external document are actually distinct processes. I think we could make a parallel between this and having multiple kinds of locks: they can all be opened, but all in very different ways that would be hard to generalize.

Therefore, so far the most logical route seems to be splitting the current concrete `Document` into `Document` (abstract base class) and `LocalDocument`. The `overwrite` operation would be implemented on both `LocalDocument` and `ExternalDocument`. Both implementations could leverage an internal `overwrite` implementation living in the `Document` abstract class for parts of the process that are similar.

Obviously clients would have to know what type of document they are dealing with in order to process an `overwrite`.

Any new suggestions in light of those precisions?

Comment: Can you clarify: " I want to track the externalEventId that triggered the change" ... "I shouldn't strengthen precondition" What exactly does "track" mean, and how does it constitute a strengthening of the preconditions of `overwrite`?

Comment: Also worth noting: the fact that in the "real world" an `ExternalDocument` is a `Document` is not in itself sufficient justification to make `ExternalDocument` a subclass of `Document`. Consider the famous [square/rectangle problem.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/238176/109689)

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Ok so basically changes to an `ExternalDocument` are triggered by receiving an event from a remote system in which case I want to track the `ID` of the event that triggered the change along with the new state. Both `overwrite` and `externalOverwrite` are probably distinct operations. However, `externalDocument.overwrite` shouldn't normally take place as we do not have authority over those documents.

Comment: I would probably model that by having something like a `PurposeForChange` (or something like that) interface, which is an input to `overwrite`. In the general document case, it can be `NoReason` object (until you have a business requirement to track why those happened, too), and in the `ExternalDocument`, it can be a different object that contains the id of the external event that triggered the change. Unfortunately without covariant types, you don't have a way of saying that `ExternalDocument.overwrite` excepts a `ExternalDocumentChangeReason` instead of a `PurposeForChange`

Comment: What about a `Document` abstract class with `StandardDocument` and `ExternalDocument`. The abtract class wouldn't expose any operation but I could still use it in the repository's contract. However, service classes must now cast to explicit document types, but they kinda need to anyway since we deal with those types differently.

Comment: By "any operation" I mean the overwrite operation. There are still operations common to both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113890/discussion-between-alexander-reinstate-monica-and-plalx).

Comment: You are going to have a problem in the future with the design you're proposing, very tightly coupling the document and external document together. In the long run, the best approach is to model the external document as a decorator to a document, taking a `Document` instance as an argument for composition. In your case, you should give up the inheritance altogether.

Comment: @plalx I posted and then deleted that abstract base class idea. Technically it will work, but there are better solutions like Alexander and Andy are proposing.

Comment: @Andy I guess I could give-up on inheritance all-together. It can be a bit annoying though if 99% of other operations should be inherited. The caller needs to know which type of document it's dealing with to carry out the overwrite operation in all cases it seems, so I guess declaring the operation on the concrete specializations without having it in the base class could make sense?

Comment: @RikD Given that `overwrite` and `externalOverwrite` are conceptually two distinct processes I think removing the operation from the base class seems to make the most sense in the end, no? All the solutions require the client to know what process it's fulfilling anyway, whether a `reason` is used or generic types could be used.

Comment: Any "is a" is a form of classification and implies a classification criterion. E.g., in ordinary geometry a square is not a circle, but in topology it is (because the criterion there is the way the thing is connected). For us (when it comes to interface/type inheritance), the criterion is: this thing abstractly "behaves as that other thing" in some defined way. So if `ExternalDocument` doesn't behave as a `Document`, then it's not a specialization of a `Document`. Now, it is possible that you've defined the behavior of the `Document` too narrowly - that's worth considering too.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović So assuming there are 10 other operations which are shared and behave properly does it make sense to inherit and implement `overwrite` on the specializations only?

Comment: I don't know enough about your problem domain, but here are a few thoughts. If you cannot really make this work in an elegant way, maybe you could separate the concepts of document and document changes. You mentioned events. One possible route is to reconceptualize so that instead of having an overwrite method, you have something that produces an Overwrite command (which is an object that holds the parameters of the former `overwrite` method as immutable private fields); a derivative command could similarly store an `externalEventId`, and all could have a common interface (e.g. `execute()`.

Comment: P.S. Of course, I can't know if this is feasible whithout being familiar with the codebase, but perhaps this line of reasoning can help you think out of the box and come up with a good idea.

Comment: P.P.S. But this is one of the problems that arise when objects have too many responsibilities, and you need to have an abstraction organized around them - the more things they can do, the harder it is to come up with a generalization that's still useful. So, splitting this class may be a good idea anyway (at lest it's something to consider).

Comment: @plalx I will undelete my abstract base class answer, to allow comments on the idea.

Comment: It's very hard to read when you use code highlighting to highlight non-code. Just because you refer to a thing declared or called  code doesn't mean you are writing code.

Comment: *[...] It can be a bit annoying though if 99% of other operations should be inherited. [...]* This is why the `ExternalDocument` contains a `Document` instance, which is accessible through a getter and on which operations may be executed (alternatively you can introduce proxy methods, something like this: https://pastebin.com/ssn92bxS).

Comment: @Andy If I have to go all the way to dispatch 99% of the operations or implement a proxy what's the advantage over inheriting `AbstractDocument` that contains all those operations and implement the 1% on specializations? I'm all for composition over inheritance, but delegating all operations clearly is a smell IMO.

Comment: LSP says not to strengthen the precondition, but that doesn't mean you can't modify/refactor the original Document class as needed.  Further, you don't say how the precondition has been strengthened.  If you require two extra id's in the constructor of `ExternalDocument`, then the information is there to use whenever overwritten.  Otherwise there's not enough information here to understand the issue.

Comment: @ErikEidt See comments below Rik D's answer.

Comment: We don't know the workflow around Documents, when the id's are generated relative to the the ExternalDocument, relative to overwrite.  We know that overwrite takes (a,b,c), but that is not really informative.  One might guess there are two different workflows here (internal vs. external), that the external document workflow might best be handled by an external document update manager class that knows and handles the id's.  I still assert that we don't have enough information which is why this question has such varied and speculative answers that do not really seem actionable.

Comment: @ErikEidt It's quite simple. Local documents can be overwrote by a local/user process. External documents are a reflection of documents existing in an external system. I want to communicate the fact that we do not have authority over external documents. The state of those documents is updated in response to remote system events and I want to be able to correlate every state change with the `externalEventId`. Some local document operations remain valid on the external ones though, like adding notes, assigning the document, etc. I'm also trying to keep the logic business logic within the model.

Comment: @Filip Milovanović Updated the question.

Comment: @Andy Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, LSP says that everywhere you use a `Document` you should be able to use an `ExternalDocument`.  This is why you cannot strengthen the precondition.  As a consequence, `externalDocument.overwrite(a, b, c)` should be valid whenever `document.overwrite(a, b, c)`.  If overwrite means just not to change the `externalDocumentId` everything is fine (I could overwrite an external document with the content of an internal document that would replace the content of the external document without changing its identity).

So far so good.  But you seem to introduce and additional responsibility to track the origin on the top of external documents.  This is no longer about extending the concept of `Document`: **It's adding new responsibilities**.  Objectively, it seems to me that tracking change events could also make sense for internal documents.

For this reason, your `ExternalDocument` appears to be only in part an extension.  The best way to improve the design is tho ensure separation of concerns between the real extension and the additional responsibilities:

- limit the `ExternalDocument` to a `Document` extension that is LSP compliant;
- use the [decorator pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html) to add to a `Document` or an `ExternalDocument` the responsibility of tracking change events.

Comment: Ok, but what if it is prohibited to manually (locally) override an `ExternalDocument`? If that behavior is inherited and prevented we come back to the LSP violation.

Comment: @plalx one can override a method.  But one does not override a class.  The decorator pattern does not override a class: it uses composition over inheritance in conjunction  to add responsibilities.  So I don't fully get your additional question.  If there were requirements missing in your question,  please add them there :-)

Comment: I am well aware what the decorator pattern is. What I mean is that decorators must extend `Document`. If the `overwrite` operation is defined in `Document` then we have the same problem with a decorator or a sub-class. I think the only sane solution is not to define the `overwrite` operation on the base class extended by `ExternalDocument`. An `overwrite` is not the same business process as an `externalOverwrite` in the end...

Comment: @plalx the problem is not the same for the decorator  the decorator **adds** new functionality.  So you don't touch the exisitng (extended) logic of the parent (i.e. overwrite without event). And if you don't touch parent, there is no LSP issue.  What you'd do, is to add a an `externalOverwrite()` (or better, a `traceableOverwrite()` to make it useful on any kind of documents).

Comment: @plalx But if you want to make the native overwrite unusable and force the event-based vriant, there there is no need for a decorator, because indeed you'd violate LSP in one way or another.  Then just accept it in your design for justified reason, but don't forget that you'll loose a couple of benefits and increase nasty risks

Comment: If I understood things well, the core problem (in terms of LSP) is that the Document type assumes that overwrite can be called at any time, but now External Document requires you to set an event ID before you can call overwrite (which can be achieved with a decorator, through its constructor), but there also seems to be a constraint that you only call overwrite in response to an event, and that's a bit trickier - you'd have to re-wrap the (external) doc in a decorator every time. This could be OK, but it could also mess up the semantics of the client code, depending on what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this using inheritance is to create an abstract base class `BaseDocument` that has all the functionality your current `Document` class has.

Both `Document` and `ExternalDocument` can now implement their own `overwrite` method.

Edit: I deleted this answer because the `overwrite` method is not part of the base class. Therefor it’s not possible to ‘*program to an interface*’. I undeleted this answer to allow others to leave comments for the OP why this approach is not  ideal.

Comment: Actually, if the OP can find a way to treat Document and ExternalDocument separately for the purposes of overwriting, and the same for other purposes, then it's fine to have a base class or an IDocument interface *without* the overwrite method, so this could be a feasible solution.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I think this is the best solution so far. `overwrite` and `externalOverwrite` are two distinct processes which should be modeled as such. If all documents can't be overwrote in the same way then the base class shouldn't implement that operation obviously. If I had to design up-front that's probably what I would have done, but since `Document` already existed I only thought of problems inheriting `Document` would cause. Given there are other shared operations inheriting seems to make sense instead of using composition and dispatching most.

Comment: It's like if we were modeling locks. They may all have common attributes and certain common operations, but they are all opened differently, hence `open` couldn't be part of a base class. Some would model `open(key)`, others `open(combination)`. The client has to know the type of lock he's dealing with. In that case perhaps composition would make sense like `Lock` configured with a `LockType` strategy, but in that case it would have to be generic so that `open(T)` matches `LockType<T>` which is not something I can do in my language.

Comment: We could always model the opening process using a visitor such as `lock.open(lockOpenerVisitor)`, which double-dispatches to `lock.openWithKey(key)`, but ultimately the specific `Lock` specializations must implement their own `open` operation or at least a different protocol for opening e.g. `lock.insertKey(key); lock.turnKey() -> LockOpened`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure all local documents can be overwritten?

They might be read-only, be it due to access-control or whatever. In which case, I would expect some error-indication.

Thus, an `ExternalDocument` objecting when you try would not violate the base contract at all, even if it does so unconditionally.

Comment: That's what I though, at first - you can just say that the overwrite method can throw an exception (even though the base class never does that), and LSP violation is gone, when it comes to exceptions. But, if I understood the question well, the strengthened precondition really comes from the fact that, with the external document, you can't call overwrite anymore at will (once you have an instance); you have to obtain an event id first, and somehow plug it into the object - and this is what actually messes with clients that need to *use* Document polymorphically.

Comment: Exactly, processing an external document override requires additionnal inputs such as the externalEventId as a correlation ID.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović That there is a different way to accomplish some action is independent from the inherited way always being denied. The different way is a pure extension, and thus cannot violate LSP.

Comment: @Deduplicator - I'm not sure if we understood each other, but the problem is the client; if there's no LSP violation, you don't have to change the client at all (e.g., you may find a way to deal with the event id somewhere else, before the documents are accessed by client code, and it would all just work). However, if the OP cannot find a way to make this work without changing client code, this is precisely what indicates an LSP violation (in the design as it now, against witch the client was written).

Comment: I'm not saying that this cannot be reconceptualized in a way similar to what you're suggesting, or otherwise redesigned. My point was that exception/denial is not the actual problem OP is trying to deal with, it's just something that appeared as a consideration to the OP while trying to work out through the underlying issue (this new document derivative breaking expectations assumed when clients of Document were written; the OP can't find a clean way to fit it into existing structures).

Comment: P.S. For clarity; imagine there's a function that processes a list of documents (polymorphically). It calls `overwrite`, perhaps multiple times. There's no room there to deal with event id's (unless you change the code and check the type). If you can't arrange for the (external) docs themselves to contain correct event id's before each `overwrite` call, then, sure, you can make it "work" by just deniyng all external documents. But the OP still needs to handle them elsewhere, somehow. In other words, if this solves the LSP problem, it does so *pro forma*, and not in a meaningful way.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I would consider the client deciding to overwrite and the client receiving and dispatching an event causing an overwrite two completely different things. Shoehorning the latter due to partial superficial similarity into the former is causing the OPs current pain. It's just too different to fit properly.

Comment: I agree with that (that's essentially what I said in my comments to the question itself - it's probably better to rethink some of the aspects of the design and separate this responsibility out in one way or another).

Answer (score 0):

There are two different situations: One, you use inheritance so that an "ExternalDocument" can be used wherever a "Document" can be used. In that situation it should have compatible behaviour. A caller should have no need to know whether they have a Document or an ExternalDocument.

There are other situations where a caller knows nothing about "Document". They are not interested one bit how ExternalDocument is implemented, including that it is a subclass of "Document". It stands on its own. You will never ever be using an ExternalDocument in a place where a different subclass of Document can be used. That's rare. If that's the case, and you don't ever substitute one for the other, then there are no violations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add extra parameters to a method without changing the method signature, inject a context object into the constructor. ie

```
ExternalDoc
   ExternalDoc(IContext context)

   public override Overwrite(a,b,c)
   {
      base.Overwrite(a,b,c)
      this.trackChange(this.context.ExternalEventId, "Overwritten")
   }
```

Prior to calling overwrite, you set the ExternalEventId in the context, which you keep a reference to after passing it into the ExternalDoc constructor